# Adding yesterdays date to a filename for weekdays only

Tags: powershell

Can I use powershell to add yesterdays date YYMMDD to my fiilename only for weekdays.  So get-date -1 but for Monday how do I get Friday's date?

Comment: `(GetDate).AddDays(-3)` for Mondays, `(GetDate).AddDays(-1)` for other days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yash Gupta mentioned in comments you'll want to identify those files created on Monday and use .AddDays(-3) to get the previous Friday's date

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\temp' -File | Rename-Item -NewName {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek -eq [System.DayOfWeek]::Monday) {
        $_.BaseName + '_' + $_.LastWriteTime.Date.AddDays(-3).ToString('yyMMdd') + $_.Extension
    }
    else {
        $_.BaseName + '_' + $_.LastWriteTime.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyMMdd') + $_.Extension
    }
} -WhatIf
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  This runs without error, but it does not rename the file.           

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Automated Crystal Reports\Output\Filename' -File | Rename-Item -NewName {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek -eq [System.DayOfWeek]::Monday) {
        $_.BaseName + '_' + $_.LastWriteTime.Date.AddDays(-3).ToString('yyMMdd') + $_.Extension
    }
    else {
        $_.BaseName + '_' + $_.LastWriteTime.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyMMdd') + $_.Extension
    }
} -WhatIf

Comment: Remove `-Whatif` from the end once you are comfortable with the changes it will make.  It's a good idea to always use -whatif to test commands before running them

Comment: Hello,I did remove the -Whatif-  The code runs without error but does not add the date on the end of the file.  The file is renamed to the same name.

Comment: You updated the path in the first line to the path of the file you needed renamed?  Try adding `-Verbose` to where the `-Whatif` switch was and checking the output

Comment: okay- so when i run the above by itself it renames the file correctly.  my powershell is importing and adding headers then skip-1 to remove the old header row and then exporting the csv file to the name above in the noted path.  When this code runs next it does not rename the file.

Comment: Please post a new question showing this code and the new issue.

Comment: I added another insert and then the code runs as expected.  thank you for the great feedback.